# How to integrate Zipkin tracing to thrift microservices

Tags: spring-boot, thrift, zipkin

i know this is a very general question but i simply don't know how to start.
I have spring-boot applications which serve a thrift API via HTTP.
The same or another spring-boot app is using the thrift-client of another application to communicate.

my goal is to trace the communication path with zipkin.
i could imagine, i need to somehow intercept incoming and outcoming http-calls with the application-type x-thrift but simply have no idea how to do this and properly integrate with zipkin libraries.

any hint how to start on this is highly appreciated, thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

i think i found a suitable way to do this. After further thinking my idea went into the direction of using annotations and aspects for intercepting HTTP requests from/to thrifts http client which seems to be quite some work.

after further search, i found this library for spring-boot serving exactly my needs:
https://github.com/aatarasoff/spring-thrift-starter

Comment: Do you have a sample for this?